# OpenCV VideoCapture Not Working in Diamondback?

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I recently updated my diamondback version to the latest version and I realised that my packages that I had written previously that used OpenCV's VideoCapture (webcam) fail to work. That is the code:

cv::VideoCapture capture;

capture.open(0);

always returns FALSE. When I compile the latest OpenCV 2.2 library outside the ROS framework and run it, my web cam is always initialised properly so I know its not a problem with OpenCV. My webcam works fine with Cheese as well so it's not at fault too. I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with a full clean install of ROS Diamondback with the required vision-opencv stacks.

Has anyone else had the same experience? Or does anyone have any advice for me to take?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10163/opencv-videocapture-not-working-in-diamondback?/) by [dkst](https://answers.ros.org/users/645/dkst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-06-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) on 2011-06-11**:
Hi, dkst, have u solved this problem yet? I go through this problem, and have no idea about it. I reinstall my ROS, but it also doesn't work.

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-06-07**:
Do you have an isolated test case that runs properly when linked against your manually compiled OpenCV libraries works, and does not work if linked against the pre-built OpenCV libraries in Diamondback? That would be pretty strange. Did you check out OpenCV 2.2 from branches/2.2 in revision 5206?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, the ROS opencv packge (opencv2) does not build the video interface options - we took this decision early because of the fragility of the OpenCV video capture and I/O code.

In use this tends not to be a problem because we usually source images via ROS, and use cv_bridge to import images (or sequences of images for video) into OpenCV.

---

Originally posted by [James Bowman](https://answers.ros.org/users/4/james-bowman/) with karma: 136 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-06-20**:
See also: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4980

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That problem falls to me unluckily, after i arrange my older openCV libraries for trying to solve the problem that it can't open local video file.

I think it disorder the connections between vision_opencv. I haven't any constructively suggestion, except to re-install diamondback.

Anyone has some better advice?

---

Originally posted by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) with karma: 133 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-30**:
I would have surely used this Idea if the others didn't work.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was having the same problem trying to use create_webcam. It looks like there is just something wrong with whatever version of opencv gets installed through the ros repositories. My quick and dirty solution was to compile/install opencv from source, and then copy all of the libraries into the ros opencv/lib directory:

$ roscd opencv2/opencv

$ sudo mv lib/ lib.orig/

$ mkdir lib

$ cd lib

$ sudo cp libopencv* ./

Hopefully ros will get this sorted out soon, but this fix is working for me at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [nicktheanimal25](https://answers.ros.org/users/678/nicktheanimal25/) with karma: 11 on 2011-06-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) on 2011-06-12**:
I have just solved with this problem. For ROS originally doesn't support ffmpeg, we should turn on those flags at Makefile in "Opencv2" in "vision_opencv" , and then rebuild it.  By the way, if ros in /opt/, it doesn't rebuild very well, so I copy  "vision_opencv" into my "~/".  Hope for helping u.

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-30**:
Cool pal.That's so cool.